# How to copy a jar produced by one Gradle sub-project into another in a single build

Tags: gradle

A multi-project Gradle build (minimal reproduction below) seems to be unable to pick up a jar file from one project and import it as a jar file in another when using a copy task.

Build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.dorongold.plugins:task-tree:1.5"
    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    subproject.apply plugin: com.dorongold.gradle.tasktree.TaskTreePlugin
}

project(":jarBuild") {
    apply plugin: "java"
}

project(":assemblyBuild") {
    apply plugin: "maven"
    configurations {
        compile
    }
    dependencies {
        compile(project(path: ":jarBuild"))
    }
    task copyFiles {
        copy {
            from configurations.compile
            into buildDir
        }
    }
    copyFiles.dependsOn(project(':jarBuild').tasks.assemble)
    build.dependsOn(copyFiles)
}

task clean
clean.dependsOn(subprojects.collect { it.tasks.matching { it.name == "clean" } })
```

This command demonstrates the issue:

```
gradle clean && gradle build && find . -name '*.jar' && gradle build && find . -name '*.jar'
```

Command Output:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 594ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 617ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
./jarBuild/build/libs/jarBuild.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 590ms
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date
./assemblyBuild/build/jarBuild.jar
./jarBuild/build/libs/jarBuild.jar
```

After the first `build`, there is no jar packaged in the build directory of `assemblyBuild`. On the second run of `build` the jar IS copied.

Proper task dependency has been verified:

```
gradle :assemblyBuild:build taskTree

> Task :assemblyBuild:taskTree

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :assemblyBuild
------------------------------------------------------------

:assemblyBuild:build
+--- :assemblyBuild:assemble
+--- :assemblyBuild:check
\--- :assemblyBuild:copyFiles
     \--- :jarBuild:assemble
          \--- :jarBuild:jar
               \--- :jarBuild:classes
                    +--- :jarBuild:compileJava
                    \--- :jarBuild:processResources
```

I have tried many different variations on this approach, including copying the jar file by referencing the direct path, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The copy command was being executed during task configuration, not execution. Replacing that task definition with this worked:

```
    task copyFiles {
        doLast {
            copy {
                from configurations.compile
                into buildDir
            }
        }
    }
```